# "Cannot resolve symbol (...)" when using a custom Typescript Declaration File

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I don't seem to be able to properly create a custom Typescript Declaration file for a javascript library that I created. This is a simplified version of my code:

### App.ts:

```
/// <reference path="types.d.ts" />

MyMethods.doSomething() // error: Cannot resolve symbol "MyMethods"
```

### Types.d.ts:

```
interface MyMethods {
    doSomething();
}

declare var MyMethods: MyMethods;
```

I don't understand why this simple declaration file doesn't work. Using Visual Studio 2015 + Resharper, `MyMethods` in App.ts is highlighted in red and the error message says Cannot resolve symbol "MyMethods".

Even weirder, the project actually compiles and the output works. What am i doing wrong?

**Edit:** if I disable Resharper, no error is highlighted. I guess it could just be a bug?

Answer (score -1):

you can hide/ supress those kind of errors as follows.

1) find code issues in the file 
2) select that perticular issue 'DataTemplate.DataType Cannot resolve symbol 'component'' from Inspection results bar. 
3) choose 'choose ReSharper | Windows | Solution Errors' 
4) You will be able to see small window 'Errors/Warnings in Solution ' 
5) select the issue and select ignore error.